# Openshift rhcloud SSL not valid certificate

Tags: ssl, openshift

I have problem with alias on openshift. There is a problem and I’m trying to figure it out few week without any result.

```
Openshift link: https://mydomain.rhcloud.com **WORKING FINE**
Alias: https://server.mydomain.com **WORKING FINE**

Openshift link: https://mydomain.rhcloud.com:8443 **WORKING FINE**
Alias: https://server.mydomain.com:8443 **NOT WORKING**
```

when I use port with new alias there is a problem with certificate -> Safari can't verify the identity of the website see screenshot. 
Please Help.

alias without :8443
[image]

alias with :8443
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Custom SSL certificates do not currently work with websockets (port 8443) on OpenShift Online.  To use secure websockets (wss) you would have to use the default *.rhcloud.com certificate.

Comment: That's kind of problem for me because I have to use the custom domain because the domain is in mobile applications already and and I can not change it so it means there is only one solution change openshift for something else? Could you recommend me something? Thank you